# Browser compatibility issues with Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Bootstrap in my MVC 5 application. The problem is that it works well on Firefox 35 an above but the UI gets disturbed when I open on IE 9 and IE 10.

Also, button colors that I am using appear as white on IE.

I want to make the application compatible to all the browsers.

Is this the problem with Bootstrap or CSS? What changes to make to make site work well on all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the **[Browser and device support](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support)** for bootstrap for supported and not supported features.

Additionaly [Wall of browser bugs](http://getbootstrap.com/browser-bugs/#browser-bugs) for some more information of known browser bugs.